# Is there a way to call a method from my Activity in my Dialog fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, methods, dialog

I am making a hangman game in Android Studio using Java. I have a button "Guess" which opens a dialog that includes an edit text and two buttons. One of the buttons is to confirm the guess so it gets the text entered (`guessedWord`) and compares it to the hangman word (`wordToGuess`). If it's wrong it adds an image and if it's correct the user wins the game. The method to compare the words is in my activity (`GameActivity.java`) but the button press is in my Dialog Fragment (`GuessWord.java`). I am trying to call the method `guessWord()` in the Dialog Fragment but I get an error when I click on the confirm button:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.hangman.GameActivity.guessWord()' on a null object reference

I tried using a getter and setter to send the inputted text. Code below (UPDATE - Included full dialog and more in the activity):

GameActivity.java

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GuessWord guessWord;

    private void openGuessDialog() {
        guessWord = GuessWord.newInstance();
        guessWord.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), GuessWord.TAG);
    }
    public void runGuessWord() {
        GuessWord guessedWordInput = new GuessWord();
        guessedWordInput.setGuessedWord("");
        guessedWord = guessedWordInput.getGuessedWord();

        if (!guessedWord.equals("")) {
            if (guessedWord.equals(wordToGuess)) {
                gameWin();
            } else {
                wrongGuesses += 1;
                setImage();
                if (wrongGuesses == 7) {
                    gameOver();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GuessWord.java:

```
public class GuessWord extends DialogFragment {
    private GameActivity gameActivity;
    public String guessedWord;
    public EditText guessEntered;
    public static final String TAG = "guess";

    public static GuessWord newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        GuessWord fragment = new GuessWord();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_guess, container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setCancelable(false);
        closeGuess();
        confirmGuess();
    }

    private void closeGuess() {
        Button closeGuess = getView().findViewById(R.id.btnCloseGuess);
        closeGuess.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dismiss();
        });
    }

    private void confirmGuess() {
        Button confirmGuess = getView().findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmGuess);
        EditText guessEntered = getView().findViewById(R.id.etGuess);
        confirmGuess.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            guessedWord = guessEntered.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
            if (guessedWord.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter a guess!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                dismiss();
                System.out.println("Text Input = " + guessedWord);
                gameActivity.runGuessWord();
            }
        });
    }

    public String getGuessedWord() {
        return guessedWord;
    }
    public void setGuessedWord(String guessedWord) {
        this.guessedWord = guessedWord;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please just try to pass the GameActivity object inside the DialogFragment class if you have not used this way
Like

```
Class GameActivity{

  show dialog(){
     GuesWord(this).show()
   }
}

class GuesWord{

  GameActivit activity
  GuesWord(GameActivit activity){
     this.activity = activity
   }

    // Then call the method of GameActivity by using object activity where you want like activity.guesword()

}
```

Or You can also try with Interface and pass anonymous object of interface inside DialogFragment class and call the method and override inside GameActivity to get further task there

Hope it may help you

Answer (score 0):

In GuessWord File, gameActivity variable is null which is why it is showing such error.

"gameActivity" variable should not be null at "gameActivity.guessWord();"  line.

You can solve this issue using 3 ways.

1. Declare the dialog in the GameActivity so that you can call its method directly.
2. Pass the interface similar to onClickListener.
3. Pass the activity object as constructor parameter and make the guessword method public.